# StreamWriter not writing out the last few characters to a file

Tags: c#, iostream

We are having an issue with one server and it's utilization of the StreamWriter class. Has anyone experienced something similar to the issue below? If so, what was the solution to fix the issue?

```
  using( StreamWriter logWriter = File.CreateText( logFileName ) )
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
      logWriter.WriteLine( "Process completed successfully." );
  }
```

When writing out the file the following output is generated:

```
  Process completed successfully.
  ...  (497 more lines)
  Process completed successfully.
  Process completed s
```

Tried adding logWriter.Flush() before close without any help. The more lines of text I write out the more data loss occurs.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but the call to Close is redundant... The StreamWriter will be disposed at the end of the using block anyway

Comment: Yep, updated the post and removed that line. Thanks!

Comment: Nobody would write a logging method like this.  It overwrites previously logged lines.  What does the code *really* look like?

Comment: Are you able to reproduce it with this small piece of code you posted? Aren't you—in the real application—accessing the stream from multiple threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cannot reproduce this.

Under normal conditions, this should not and will not fail.

- Is this the actual code that fails ? The text "Process completed" suggests it's an extract.
- Any threading involved?
- Network drive or local?
- etc.

Comment: After a lot of digging by several of us, we have come to the conclusion that this truncation is being caused by enabling compression on dynamic content for the web site.  We have been able to recreate the truncation issue locally and it disappeared when we disabled compression.

Answer (score 20):

Had a very similar issue myself. I found that if I enabled AutoFlush before doing any writes to the stream and it started working as expected. 
`logWriter.AutoFlush = true;`

Comment: This fixed my problem perfectly. Might just fixed the one the OP asking the question had.

Comment: The reason this fixed my problem: my StreamWriter was being swept up [as its caller went out of scope] before it could finish pushing out its last few lines.

Comment: 10 years later, this is still fixes this weird problem.

Answer (score 6):

sometimes even u call flush(), it just won't do the magic. becus Flush() will cause stream to write most of the data in stream except the last block of its buffer.

```
try
{
 // ... write method
 // i dont recommend use 'using' for unmanaged resource
}
finally
{
 stream.Flush();
 stream.Close();
 stream.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Excellent Solution for the same issue i had. Thanks @Bonshington

Answer (score 1):

This certainly appears to be a "flushing" problem to me, even though you say you added a call to Flush().  The problem may be that your StreamWriter is just a wrapper for an underlying FileStream object.

I don't typically use the File.CreateText method to create a stream for writing to a file; I usually create my own FileStream and then wrap it with a StreamWriter if desired.  Regardless, I've run into situations where I've needed to call Flush on both the StreamWriter and the FileStream, so I imagine that is your problem.

Try adding the following code:

```
            logWriter.Flush();
            if (logWriter.BaseStream != null)
                logWriter.BaseStream.Flush();
```

Comment: I was thinking about the same, but `StreamWriter` is flushing the underlying stream in its `Dispose`.

Answer (score 1):

Using framework 4.6.1 and under heavy stress it still has this problem. I'm not sure why it does this, though i found a way to solve it very differently (which strengthens my feeling its indeed a .net bug).

In my case i tried write huge jagged arrays to disk (video caching). 
Since the jagged array is quite large it had to do lot of repeated writes to store a large set of video frames, and despite they where uncompressed and each cache file got exact 1000 frames, the logged cash files had all different sizes.

I had the problem when i used this

```
//note, generateLogfileName is just a function to create a filename()

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(generateLogfileName(), FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
  using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs)
  {
    // do your stuff, but it will be unreliable
  }
}
```

However when i provided it an Encoding type, all logged files got an equal size, and the problem was gone.

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(generateLogfileName(), FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
  {
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs,Encoding.Unicode))
    {
      // all data written correctly,  no data lost.
    }
 }
```

Note also read the file width the same encoding type!

Comment: This solution worked for me, after spending far too much time trying to find the rest of my file. Such a frustrating bug.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this is what I found with output file

**Case 1: Without Flush() and Without Close()**

Character Length = 23,371,776

**Case 2: With Flush() and Without Close()**

```
logWriter.flush()
```

Character Length = 23,371,201

**Case 3: When propely closed**

```
logWriter.Close()
```

Character Length = 23,375,887 (Required)

So, In order to get proper result, always need to close Writer instance.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem

Following worked for me

```
using (StreamWriter tw = new StreamWriter(@"D:\Users\asbalach\Desktop\NaturalOrder\NatOrd.txt"))
{
    tw.Write(abc.ToString());// + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Comment: what's the fix here ?

Answer (score -1):

This did the trick for me:

```
streamWriter.flush();
```

Comment: Any additional explanation would improve your answer.